# As a Windows 7 x64 user with a 4TB GPT-initialised disk, why is it showing as 1677.90GB?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, 64-bit

I have a new 4TB internal hard drive that I would like to use solely for data.

I am using the popular (but old) Intel BAD AXE 2 ([D975XBX](http://www.intel.com/products/motherboard/d975xbx/)) motherboard, Windows 7 x64 and a GPT-initialised disk that is plugged into a SATA port powered by the Intel controller. However the unallocated space in Disk Manager is showing as `1677.90GB`. **Why is this?**

Similar issues point to people having initialised large disks using MBR or attempting to use them on 32-bit OS's – I am doing neither of those things, which leaves me stumped.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it is 32 bit or 64 bit

Comment: To OS bit-size doesn't matter. That's a red herring. Is your Win7 using AHCI or RAID drivers for the SATA ? If not hat might be the cause. Also: The BIOS/SATA controller itself must properly be able to handle such large disks.

Comment: @Tonny, I am using AHCI mode. Regarding the 64-bit argument, the Microsoft article (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2581408) seems to say that Windows 32-bit cannot address HDD's larger than 2.2TB. I have not been able to find anything on the controller itself, but I do know that other ones its age *do* support 48bit LBA.

Comment: @Check12 - That article clearly indicates that a 32-bit version of Windows 7 on a GPT disk can access more then 2.2TB of data..

Comment: @Check12 Most controllers from that time may support it, but not all. And BIOS must co-operate as well. It is by no means a given that a Bios can handle it. I have just last month seen a 2015 Bios that barfed on a 3 TB disk connected to the eSata port. (It is a laptop. Seems the manufacturer didn't bother to test, because the internal HDD's they sell them with just go to 1 TB max.)

Comment: @Ramhound, so it does. I was mistaken after reading "The 2-TB barrier is the result of this 32-bit limitation", but, also, my drive manufacturer has written an article (https://www.hgst.com/support/high-capacity-hard-drives) that seems to imply 32-bit OS's don't support these large drives.

Comment: @Tonny, thanks for the update. It sounds like this could be a problem with my old hardware then.